# Do mucous membranes surround visceral organs?

Tags: physiology, anatomy

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucous_membrane) claims that:

> A mucous membrane or mucosa is a membrane that lines various cavities in the body and surrounds internal organs.

The first part of that sentence is clearly accurate, but I cannot find any reference from Google Scholar or books that states mucous membranes *surround* internal organs.

The mucous layer lines the lumens of the body: digestive, respiratory,urogenital tracts, as well as cavities leading to openings such as the ears and nose, and forms the conjunctiva of eyes. The surfaces of internal organs don't fit any of these categories.

I think wikipedia is wrong about the viseral organ part, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

"[Serous membrane](http://physrev.physiology.org/content/6/2/242.short)" might be what the Wikipedia editor was thinking of, for example the [pleura of the lungs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4332049/); other examples include the pericardium and peritoneum.